# Trying to fix PHPStan Issues with Laravel's MorphTo relations and Model properties

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstan

We recently started using PHPStan 1.10 at level 6 in a Laravel 10 PHP 8.2 project.
It reports a few remaining issues in the following model that I would like to fix.

```php
class ArticlePrice extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['cost_type_id', 'type', 'type_id', 'amount'];

    /**
     * @var array<string> $with
     */
    protected $with = ['types'];

    /**
     * @return MorphTo
     */
    public function types(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo('types', 'type', 'type_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        if ($this->types) {
            return $this->type === Article::class ? $this->types->vdm_code : $this->types->name;
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

For the `types()` MorphTo it reports:

```
phpstan: Method App\Models\Environment\CostType\ArticlePrice::types() 
return type with generic class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo 
does not specify its types: TRelatedModel, TChildModel
```

But if I change it into `MorphTo<Model, Article|Category>` which reflects the actually models it could return at this point it complains about:

```
phpstan: Method App\Models\Environment\CostType\ArticlePrice::types() should return
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model,
 App\Models\Shop\Article|App\Models\Shop\Category> 
but returns Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model,
 App\Models\Environment\CostType\ArticlePrice>.
```

which is weird to me, since we are in ArticlePrice, this seems nonsensical to me.
It has the exact same complaint when I do `<Model, Model>` instead.

The other issue is that it does not understand the content of `$types`:

```
phpstan: Access to an undefined property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$name.
phpstan: Access to an undefined property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$vdm_code.
```

I hoped fixing the morphTo issue would fix this as well, since `vdm_code` and `name` are documented properties of their models. But I fear this would not work, so this might need a different way of fixing the issue.

**In short, how can I get PHPStan to understand how my polymorphic relation works, and how do I get it to recognise properties of the polymorphic related models?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with `$types` with a workaround by adding this to the class level docblock:

```
* @property-read Article|Category|null $types
```

This makes sure PHPStan understands the types `$types` can be, and the properties it can have.

Only downside is now, I can't run `ide-helper:models` on this model, this would undo it.

And this is the way I fixed the issue with the MorphTo, though its not a satisfactory solution to me. Since to me it feels like this gives the wrong information about the relation about the possible return types. It does get rid of the PHPStan issue, but I rather have be able to give the correct information.

```
* @return MorphTo<Model, ArticlePrice>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Larastan? Enabling that extension fixes a lot of issues when analysing Laravel apps with PHPStan.

If this issue persists then it’s just a feature request / bug report you should open in Larastan.

1. To make it understand the correct return type of morphTo method.
2. To make it understand the `types` property type.

Comment: Yes we are, v2.8.1 it seems. It's also configured in `phpstan.neon`